# MS SQL Stored procedure returning unexpected results based on blank parameters

Tags: sql-server, variables, stored-procedures, parameters

I'm passing parameters to a stored procedure from an asp.net webform.

However, for one particular combination of parameters a single parameter appear to being ignored.

The parameters I'm passing that are causing the issue are as follows:

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spProgressCohorts]
    @StuYear = N'10',
    @DataCollection = N'March 2013 Teacher Assessments',
    @SubjectName = N'English',
    @TeachingGroup = N'Select All',
    @Subgroup = N'Select All',
    @KS2 = '',
    @Result = ''
```

When I run the stored procedure with these parameters the results return as though the @Result variable is being ignored.

The results the stored procedure return are (the ks2en and result columns are included for reference):

```
surname     forename    ks2en   result
El Hajj     Zeinab              D
Grzelak     Marlena             F+
Sage        Nigel
```

However, I get just get Nigel Sage's record (as expected and this is what should be returned by the stored procedure) when when I run the following query:

```
select surname, forename, ks2en, result 
    from student join subject on subject.upn=student.upn 
where datacollection='March 2013 Teacher Assessments' and stuyear='10' and name='english' and result='' and ks2en=''
```

My stored procedure is massive, so I'll just include code specific to the parameters above:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spProgressCohorts]
    @StuYear varchar(2),  
    @DataCollection varchar(100), 
    @SubjectName varchar(100), 
    @TeachingGroup varchar(30), 
    @Subgroup varchar(10), 
    @Result varchar(4), 
    @KS2 varchar(4)

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 --interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT Forename + ' ' + Surname

FROM student
   JOIN subject
     ON subject.upn = student.upn
WHERE 
    (@StuYear = [stuyear]
    AND @TeachingGroup = 'Select All'
    AND [DataCollection] = @DataCollection
    AND [Name] = @SubjectName
    AND @Subgroup='Select All'
    AND @KS2 = CASE @subjectName WHEN 'English' THEN KS2en WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN KS2ma ELSE KS2av END
    AND [Result] like @Result + '%')
OR 
    (@StuYear = [stuyear]
        AND @TeachingGroup Not Like 'Select All'
        AND [DataCollection] = @DataCollection
        AND [Name] = @SubjectName
        AND [TeachingGroup] = @TeachingGroup
        AND @Subgroup='Select All'
        AND @KS2 = CASE @subjectName WHEN 'English' THEN KS2en WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN KS2ma ELSE KS2av END
        AND [Result] like @Result + '%')

ORDER BY surname, forename
```

Comment: It is working exactly as expected. Use `=` in the stored procedure if you want an exact match. `like '%'` will match all `NOT NULL` values.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith. The problem is that I need it to search for values like the result because where I have a pararmeter passed from the webform it will be a whole grade eg A, B, C etc and the results in my results column can have + or - values eg A+, A, A-, B+, B, B- etc. Is there a way I can edit my where statement so that it deals with the case of `@result=''` and `@ks2 =''` separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
...
AND [Result] LIKE CASE @Result WHEN '' THEN '' ELSE @Result + '%' END)
```